# How to display to the console list from another class?

Tags: c#, list, methods

I have created a class called `CustomDataList` and I have the following code:

```
private List<string> students = new List<string>();

public List<string> GetList()
{
    return students;
}

public void AddStudent()
{
    students.Add("Morgan");
    students.Add("Loren");
    students.Add("Martin");
    students.Add("Ariana")
    students.Add("Nikkita");

    foreach(var element in students)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(students);
    }
}
```

I want to display to the console the list I have created. How can I proceed? How can I call the `AddStudent()` method in the Main method?

Comment: `Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLIne, students));`

Comment: You need to create an instance of CustomDataList in Main and invoke AddStudent using instanceName.AddStudent();

Comment: You need an instance of your class: `var dl = new CustomDataList(); dl.AddStudents(); Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, dl.GetList()))`

Comment: @Cid: `Environment.NewLine` for sure, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cretaed sample test, You can try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var customDataList = new CustomDataList(); 
            customDataList.AddStudent(); 
            foreach(var element in customDataList.GetList())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element);
            }
        }
    }

    public class CustomDataList {
        private List<string> students = new List<string>();
        public List<string> GetList()
        {
            return students;
        }
        public void AddStudent()
        {
            students.Add("Morgan");
            students.Add("Loren");
            students.Add("Martin");
            students.Add("Ariana");
            students.Add("Nikkita");
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Note the `foreach` block in the `AddStudent();` method. Calling `AddStudent();` should print the students.

Comment: Really helpful :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an instance of `CustomDataList` in the `Main` method.

```
var datalist=new CustomDataList ();
datalist.AddStudent();
```